# Peak current requirement for switching logic

Tags: digital-logic, voltage-regulator, current-measurement, maximum-ratings

Is there a way of estimating peak current requirements for sets of logic gates? This is to qualify the regulator.

I have a Gumstix Parlor board with a 1.8V regulator (MIC5247) at 150mA on it. This is available externally so I could power the 1.8V side of my interface board with that line. I currently have 3 level shifters (two 74LVC8T245 and one TXS0108) for a total of 24 lines.

I can guess at the total line capacitance given the LVC (6.5pF) and the OMAP datasheets (varying between 10pF and 60pF depending on what peripheral). If I call it 80pF max and then want any signal to transition in under 5ns I get I = C dv/dt = 3mA or so per transition. Multiplied by 24 = 70mA worst case.

Is this a really naive way of guesstimating the current load? Or should I just call it 100mA and provide my own 1.8V regulator? I don't have any real way of telling what the Parlor board uses itself for 1.8V...

Comment: Is your design going to go into production in combination with the Gumstix board, i.e. are you going to be selling your interface board? Or what? I am inclined to say it is otherwise OTT. The Gumstix is not particularly expensive, so give it a go and if it works it works. A bit of extra current draw is unlikely to damage the regulator components anyway - it might just become a bit glitchy under load. A solution might be to find a way to measure average peak draw and add a smoothing capacitor to supply during the transients, if there isn't one already.

Comment: It's a final prototype on a multi company project. The issue was that I didn't know if was OTT or not. Probably - I haven't bother so far with my test boards. This board would be embarrassing to get wrong so I'd rather go the OTT route ;-) It's more annoying though because the 1V8 regulator *cannot* be allowed to power on before SYSEN is asserted. And the power to the regulator must come on before SYSEN because you cannot assert enable pins on an unpowered chip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not follow how you get C dv/dt = 3mA. But here is a more accepted way of calculating the power requirement. The energy to charge 80pF to 5V is
$$ E_c = \frac{1}{2}CV^2 = 1 \cdot 10^{-9} J $$
Power is:
$$ P_c = E_c \cdot F(SwitchingFrequency) $$
Therefore the power requirement is proportional to frequency. Examples:
  F = 10MHz,  Pc = 10mW,  I_average = 2mA, times 24 = 48mA
  F = 1MHz,  Pc = 1mW,  I_average = 0.2mA, times 24 = 4.8mA

At 80pF of load capacitance per line, this is going to be dominant factor for the power dissipation. With a little margin, it is probably good enough to cover other losses.

Therefore, whether a separate regulator is needed will depend on the switching frequency.

Also, regardless of the regulator decision, local decoupling capacitors are required to smooth out the peak switching current. Here I would go with the estimate that at least hundreds of times of the load capacitance is required: 80pF x 24 x 300 = 0.576uF. A typical decoupling scheme would be 0.1uF per IC plus a 2.2uF or larger ceramic capacitor in the same vicinity.

Comment: C.dv/dt = 80p * 1.8V/5n = 3mA. Told you I was being naive <grin>! I knew that'd be peak though and my usual 100n + 10u caps would smooth peak switching current but I'm afraid I couldn't find my Art of Electronics book and thus became helpless when faced with a capacitive load calculation! I knew that the power would have to be somewhat proportional to frequency but didn't know the equations. I have SPI at 8MHz but most other lines are I2C and GPIO at sleepy 100s of kHz. I can now work them all out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your calculations also indicate that even at an over pessimistic 80pF, to 1.8V at maybe 7-8 lines or so at 8MHz and the rest at under 1MHz, the power requirement will only be in the 10s of mAs. I should easily be able to power the 1.8V side of the shifters off the main Gumstix Parlor board's 150mA regulator. Cool!